# Form List of Core Data Entities with Header Titles Through Relationships Ignoring Entities with no Related Entities

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I am trying to display Core Data information in a Form. The entities have a one to many relationship. For demo purposes I made an app that has Manufacturers and two types of products, Sprockets and Widgets. The Manufacturers are the One, and the Sprockets and Widgets are the To Many. Manufacturers are uniqued so that they can't be duplicated.

I can get the data to display where the Manufacturer names are listed in a Section header, with the products underneath. The problem I am having is that while every Manufacturer makes either a Sprocket, Widget, or both, they don't all make both. So, when I list out the data, I end up with Section Headers for Manufacturers that don't have any product beneath them. You can see in the following screenshot where Cogswell does not make widgets and Gotrockets doesn't make sprockets:
[image]

I would like to not have Cogswell shown in the widgets list and Gotrockets not shown in the sprockets list, and I can't figure out how to structure, filter or use a predicate to do this. I have also attempted to have another return only the correct information, but the compiler balks, understandably when I try to not return a view for a Manufacturer with no product. My current code is this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

@FetchRequest(entity: Manufacturer.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var manufacturers: FetchedResults<Manufacturer>

private var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    return formatter
}

private var measurementFormatter: MeasurementFormatter {
    let formatter = MeasurementFormatter ()
    formatter.unitStyle = .short
    return formatter
}


var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {

            Text("Widgets:")
            ForEach(manufacturers, id: \.self) { manufacturer in
                Section(header: Text(manufacturer.wrappedName)) {
                    ForEach(manufacturer.wrappedManufacturerOfWidget, id: \.self) { widget in
                        Text("\(widget.wrappedTitle)")
                    }
                }
            }

            Text("Sprockets:")
            ForEach(manufacturers, id: \.self) { manufacturer in
                Section(header: Text(manufacturer.wrappedName)) {
                    ForEach(manufacturer.wrappedManufacturerOfSprocket, id: \.self) { sprocket in
                        Text("\(sprocket.wrappedTitle)")
                    }
                }
            }

            Button("Add Data") {
                let spacely = Manufacturer(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                spacely.name = "Spacely"

                let cogswell = Manufacturer(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                cogswell.name = "Cogswell"

                let gotrockets = Manufacturer(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                gotrockets.name = "Gotrockets"

                let colossalSprocket = Sprocket(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                colossalSprocket.id = UUID()
                colossalSprocket.sprocketMadeBy = spacely
                colossalSprocket.title = "Colossal Sprocket"

                let cogSprocket = Sprocket(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                cogSprocket.id = UUID()
                cogSprocket.sprocketMadeBy = cogswell
                cogSprocket.title = "CogSprocket"

                let whizzoWidget = Widget(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                whizzoWidget.id = UUID()
                whizzoWidget.widgetMadeBy = gotrockets
                whizzoWidget.title = "Whizzo Widget"

                let uniblabWidget = Widget(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                uniblabWidget.id = UUID()
                uniblabWidget.widgetMadeBy = spacely
                uniblabWidget.title = "Uniblab"

                try? self.managedObjectContext.save()
            }
        }

        .navigationBarTitle("Products")
    }
}
}
```

I have searched, but have not found a solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the `manufacturers` to exclude those where the count of widgets (or sprockets) is zero.  Something like this:

```
ForEach(manufacturers.filter( { $0.wrappedManufacturerOfWidget.count > 0 }), id: \.self) { manufacturer in
```

Likewise in the `ForEach` for sprockets.

Comment: I didn't think of filtering .count on the ForEach. Now I feel stupid. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It works a charm AND is simple.